# how to use Maven to distribute dependency jars?

Tags: maven

I downloaded a Maven project and can run `mvn install` to build the target helloworld.jar which depends on several 3rd-party run-time jars. However, I am not sure how to use Maven to automatically copy these 3rd-party jars into a specific directory. Looking into pom.xml, I found the following statements. So basically I want the 3rd-party jars copied to `${project.build.directory}/lib`. To do this, which maven plugin/phrase/goal should I use? Can someone show me a runnable maven syntax? Thanks!

```
    <id>build</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <maven.test.skip>false</maven.test.skip>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependency-jar</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                    <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                    <outputDirectory>
                                        ${project.build.directory}/lib
                                    </outputDirectory>
                                    <destFileName>
                                        log4j.jar
                                    </destFileName>
                                </artifactItem>


                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                                    <version>${project.version}</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                    <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                    <outputDirectory>
                                        ${project.build.directory}/lib
                                    </outputDirectory>
                                    <destFileName>
                                        helloworld.jar
                                    </destFileName>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</profile>
```

Answer (score 0):

A list of the available build goals for the plugin specified in your POM file are available here:

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html

I suspect you want dependency:copy-dependencies

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tired dependency:copy-dependencies, but mvn creates a folder "dependency" under "target", and all jars are copied to "target/dependency" without being renamed. According to the pom.xml, I think they should be copied into "target/lib" and renamed, e.g., "log4j.jar"